# create SQL-view with parameter

Tags: sql, view, parameters

```
declare @Date DateTime
set @Date='2012-04-16'
select s.sid,'Status'=case a.sid when isnull(a.sid,null)   
then 'absent' else 'present' end from
student s left outer join (select * from absent where date=@Date) as a
on s.sid=a.sid
```

I have a sql query like this, and I need to create a view with this one.....is it possible..

I created a function for this like

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Attendance (@Date DateTime)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    select s.sid,'Status'=case a.sid when isnull(a.sid,null)   
    then 'absent' else 'present' end from
    student s left outer join (select * from absent where date=@Date) as a
    on s.sid=a.sid

)
```

the view is created successfully....but when I call the view like

```
 select * from dbo.Attendance('2012-04-11')
```

it reports error like "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."......how can I call this function

Comment: not really - views don't have parameters... you could only do the join in the view and use the parameter in the where when you query the view...

Comment: yup I'll do...thanks for ur response Yahia

Comment: You want to assign parameter value at runtime, create Stored Procedure either

Comment: you will need to cast the string to a date,cast(@Date as date) you should also explicitly check the date makes sense and raise an error if it doesn't.

Comment: BEGIN TRY
     cast(@Date as date)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     RAISERROR(' The supplied date was not recognised as valid!',16,1)
END CATCH;
N.B. look up raiserror for all options which will depend on your implementation

Comment: after the AS, declare a new variable of type date, call it \@dDate then do the try from the line above followed by the \@dDate = cast(\@Date as date) & use \@dDate in your query

Comment: don't use DateTime, it will want '2012-04-20 00:00:00'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paramerterised views are allowed in MS Access but no serious db server will allow you to construct a view that requires a mandatory parameter.

your example describes a stored procedure which should be the implementation of choice for your requirement.

another way of meeting your requirement would be to keep your @Date parameter in another table, provided it's there the view can refer to that and will return a row if the criteria is met

Comment: thanks Paddy Carroll...I dont understand how to keep the @Date in another table, can u give me the query sample

Comment: create table application_parameters( param_name varchar,param_value varchar); insert into application_parameters (param_name,param_value) values ('my_app_date','2012-04-16');

Comment: select s.sid,'Status'=case a.sid when isnull(a.sid,null)   
then 'absent' else 'present' end from
student s left outer join (select * from absent ,application_paramaters where param_name = 'my_app_date' and date = cast(my_param_value as Date)) as a
on s.sid=a.sid ----not checked but you get the idea

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a parametrized view atleast in SQL server rather use a table function.

Please refer [Create parameterized VIEW in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498364/create-parameterized-view-in-sql-server-2008) for more details.

Hope it will give you an idea.

Comment: Try taking '2012-04-11' into a datetime variable then use select * from dbo.Attendance(@myDate). I hope after this modification it should work

Answer (score 1):

View with Parameter is possible as per following info.
Please visit following link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/c11kd98s(v=vs.80).aspx

```
CREATE SQL VIEW Customer_Remote_View ;
   AS SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Customers.Country = ?cCountry
```