# Creating a SQL View with parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, view

I have a SQL Query that accepts parameters. Now When I'm trying to include that query into a view, I'm facing an error because a view cannot hold a parameters just like an SP or a function can.

Hence if I had to create the view that had to contain the parameters, Is there someway that it is possible?

Many Thanks

Comment: Views **cannot** have parameters - either you need to return everything (and then use the parameters on the select from that view), or you need to convert it into a table-valued stored function

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create parameterized VIEW in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498364/create-parameterized-view-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 8):

I don't think so you can create a parameter  in a View .But you can create a function which takes input parameter like the one below .

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Sample (@Parameter varchar(10))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
 SELECT Field1, Field2,....
 FROM YourTable
 WHERE Field3 = @Parameter
)
```

Comment: An ITVF (as opposed to a TVF/SF) is effectively a view in terms of how it is merged into the final query.

Answer (score 5):

No, [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)

> Creates a virtual table whose contents (columns and rows) are defined
>   by a query. Use this statement to create a view of the data in one or
>   more tables in the database. For example, a view can be used for the
>   following purposes:
>
> To focus, simplify, and customize the perception each user has of the
>   database.
>
> As a security mechanism by allowing users to access data through the
>   view, without granting the users permissions to directly access the
>   underlying base tables.
>
> To provide a backward compatible interface to emulate a table whose
>   schema has changed.

So, basically, this acts just like a table, and the only way that you can add "parameters" to a table is via filter statements when accessing the view

Comment: That is the most rational explanation I've heard for prohibiting parameterized views. Still stinks, though, when you need parameters to filter subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not.
Consider View as a table which contains a compiled set of data(although in actual terms view is different from table) and hence it can never have any input parameter like an sp or a function.

Answer (score 0):

View can not pass paramets directly, but you can use [context_info](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-context-info-transact-sql), for example

```
declare @v varbinary(8)
set @v = cast(cast(floor( current_timestamp as float)) as bigint) as varbinary) --
set context_info @v -- save 
select * from my_viev

create my_view as
with CTE(date) as (
  select cast(cast(substring(context_info(),1,8) as bigint) as datetime) date  -- read
)
select * from filials p
 left join filials rea on rea.number = p.number 
 and (date between         rea.dateopen and '12.12.9999')
where date between p.datestart and p.datestop
```

Answer (score -3):

You guys have never done this as a VIEW is a whole other table created by a query and you can include parameters in that query....it is freaking simple as well

build your view like you would any other with parameters....

Example:

```
USE [iepa]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[get_Batch_Data]    Script Date: 06/30/2015 11:41:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_Batch_Data]
@inparm varchar(12)
AS
select *
from batch_data
where COM_Batch_ID=@inparm
```

now call that view like this:

```
select from get_batch_data('61404')  <<<< 61404 is the parameter being passed....
```

Pretty simple and very powerful as you can use a view to provide UNALTERABLE information to a subset of a table or a union of tables.
A view is NOT the table and so there are things you sometimes cannot do.

But these are the same things you can not do when you form a very complicated join/union in a query......been using the one above since 1999 so I know it works....

Comment: While you were being condescending, you missed the fact that you created a stored procedure, not a view.

Comment: well thanks. I searched for parametrized view and the smarta** says "you stooped, use this" and writes a stored procedures.