# Should my view be much slower than my stored proc?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, sqlperformance

I have a view that I can't seem to fully tune, so I tried converting it to a proc, moving one of my WHERE conditions that I use when querying into a parameter and using the parameter in my derived tables.

*View*

```
CREATE VIEW myView
AS
SELECT     i.ItemCode
           , s.StoreID
           , ISNULL(SUM(s.TotalSales)) AS Sales
FROM       Item i
LEFT JOIN  Balance b ON i.ItemCode = b.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT    SUM(Quantity)
                      , StoreID
                      , ItemCode
                      , Date
            FROM      Sales
            GROUP BY  StoreID
                      , ItemCode
                      , Date) AS s    ON i.ItemCode = s.ItemCode
                                      AND s.Data >= COALESCE(b.Date, '01-01-1900)
JOIN
GROUP BY    i.ItemCode
            , s.StoreID
```

*Stored Proc*

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc(@StoreID INT)
AS
SELECT     i.ItemCode
           , s.StoreID
           , ISNULL(SUM(s.TotalSales)) AS Sales
FROM       Item i
LEFT JOIN  Balance b ON i.ItemCode = b.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT    SUM(Quantity)
                      , StoreID
                      , ItemCode
                      , Date
            FROM      Sales
            WHERE     StoreID = @StoreID
            GROUP BY  StoreID
                      , ItemCode
                      , Date) AS s    ON i.ItemCode = s.ItemCode
                                      AND s.Data >= COALESCE(b.Date, '01-01-1900)
JOIN
GROUP BY    i.ItemCode
            , s.StoreID
```

EXEC myProc(100) is *much* faster than SELECT * FROM myView WHERE StoreID = 100.
Should this be the case?

**Note**: I know this code may not make perfect sense or run -- I've tried to simplify it by removing some other JOINs. The only substantial difference in the real code is moving the WHERE into the derived table, which I've done here.

Shouldn't the view take my WHERE into account when performing the derived table queries and be just as fast as the proc?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm trying to use Entity Framework with this query, and a view would be much nicer to work with.

Comment: Yes, the view probably should be slower. First the view is generated: all items from Item, Balance, and the Sales subquery will be joined together. There may be quite a few records. Then, from that set, the filter is applied.  In the proc, the filter is applied first to the Sales table, then this small subset is joined to the other tables. So if the cardinality of StoreIds is small compared to the number of records in Sales, the results you are seeing would be expected.

Comment: Is there any way to have the derived queries filtered by the conditions I provide in my WHERE clause when querying the view?

Comment: A parameterized view. This [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498364/create-parameterized-view-in-sql-server-2008) seems to answer that, sort of like what you are doing. Can't really say more as I'm not familiar with sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two queries are quite different.  The difference is very subtle, but this is the line:

```
        WHERE     StoreID = @StoreID
```

The view calculates all the data for all the stores.  It then filters the results for a particular store.

The stored procedure version is only looking at the particular store; it can even make efficient use of an index on StoreId if there is one.

Comment: Right. I was hoping SQL could account for the WHERE condition I provide when querying the view as it builds its execution plan, thus filtering the derived queries. Do you know if there's a way to filter the derived queries in a view?

Comment: @BretWalker . . . that is an optimization I haven't seen.  What you probably want, though, is a table valued function.  It gives you the syntax of a view with the ability to pass an argument.