# SQL Server - Caching local data inside function

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, database-administration

Let's suppose I have this:

```
SELECT x, y, z
FROM t1
WHERE fn_ExpensiveLookup(x);
```

And let's assume `fn_ExpensiveLookup` does a lot of expensive operations (some of which could be cached just for the duration of the query/connection).

I can't use temp tables inside scalar-valued functions, and I believe table variables won't persist between function calls.

So, how can I cache some stuff inside the function?

Comment: Could you move some of the expensive "cachable" logic outside of the function and pass in the result as a 2nd parameter?

Comment: @Curt I can only change the where clause and the function. The rest of the query can't change.

Comment: you can use temp tables inside scalar-valued functions by using synonyms .not recommended way, but it possible .

Answer (score 2):

Would it be possible to re-write the UDF as a paramatized view like this:
[Create parameterized VIEW in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498364/create-parameterized-view-in-sql-server-2008)

Basically do not have a BEGIN... END. Write everything in a select inside the return statement.

Results will be reused (assuming no params are floats) and the query will become SET based. Also add WITH SCHEMABINDING.

If this is possible the query should perform like any other predicate.