# SQL Create View query Executes successfully in Management studio but fails in C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here is my code

```
                   cmd.Connection = con;
                   if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                   {
                       con.Open();
                   }
                   cmd.CommandText = "Drop View [Picklist]";
                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                   cmd.CommandText = "CREATE VIEW [Picklist] AS select A.desp_no,A.desp_date,A.custid,A.comp_name,A.ref_no,B.item_code as itemid,B.Pqty,C.serial_no,C.batchno,C.expiry,D.Item_name,D.Item_code,D.Mrp,E.cust_name,E.Address1,E.Address2,E.Address3,E.Phone,E.Email from dbo.Tbl_DespDet A inner join dbo.Tbl_Desp_Sub B on A.desp_no=B.desp_no inner join dbo.tbl_desp_barcode C on c.desp_no=A.desp_no inner join tbl_itemMast D on D.item_id=B.item_code inner join dbo.tbl_CustMast E on A.custid=E.cust_id  where A.desp_no=@despno";
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@despno", beobj._Desno);
                   try 
                   {
                       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                       return true;
                   }
                   catch(Exception ex)
                   {
                       return false;
                   }
```

the same create view statement(with just copy paste) works in Sql Server Management Studio.Some one Help me as i am stuck in this Fix.

**update**:

the name of view is given as [Picklist] for testing only.even i have tried with removind square brackets and found no difference.

Comment: **[Create parameterized VIEW in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498364/create-parameterized-view-in-sql-server-2008)**

Comment: And I guess it won't in SSMS either. You probably set value hardcoded. Like `CREATE VIEW [Picklist] AS ...  where A.desp_no=10`. So the correct way is to create table valued function and pass `desp_no` as parameter. So **could we mark it as duplicate** or your case is different?

Comment: but i have linked my report document with the view only.so its not as easy to change it to function.

Comment: There is no such thing as parametrized VIEW.

Comment: thanx.i will go with stored procedure itself.actually i have forgot the fact that view cannot be parameterized.even i have faced the same issue before.

Comment: but this was not a duplicate question.many of starter programmers will face this issue when they work with views.they wont search for parameterized views right.

Comment: **Yes, it is obvious duplicate.** But check that it was not me who mark it as duplicate. First ask then mark :)

Comment: even searching for about more than half n hou,i havent thought of the same title like 'Parameterized view'.so this is not just a duplicate.just another version of that so called parameterized view question.

Comment: any way thanks for the fix...

Comment: So do you want me to reopen it or what? Please go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ and ask if you are right.

Comment: neither i know what is the procedure of reopening nor i am bothered with my reputation loss bro :)...just wanted no one should find it difficult to get answer for this fix...so just leave as it is. thanx for u timely input bro..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106576/discussion-between-akhil-kumar-and-lad2025).

Answer (score 0):

Views cannot contain `@parameters`. What you could do is create a stored procedure (`CREATE PROCEDURE ...`) first, and then in C# code, set the name of the stored procedure as the `cmd.CommandText`.
Or alternatively, remove the `CREATE VIEW` part altogether, and keep just the query itself as the content of the `cmd.CommandText`.

Comment: thanx.i will go with stored procedure itself.actually i have forgot the fact that view cannot be parameterized.even i have faced the same issue before.