# How can I create a (server-side) filtered editable SQL recordset for Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I am working on a very complex legacy ADP project in Microsoft Access that connects to a 2008 SQL Server back end. A common usage scenario is a **form in datasheet view that contains an editable recordset**.

The approach used through most of the database is to load the form, then build the SQL dynamically in VBA using form parameters, and apply the SQL as the `RecordSource` for the form. Many of the queries are quite complex, so this makes for really ugly code and a maintenance nightmare.

For the read-only recordsets, I have converted the dynamic sql to parameterized stored proceedures, which works great. Nice and clean, and easy to maintain going forward.

But for the editable recordsets, I am **trying to determine the best approach:**

**1. Dynamic SQL** - As mentioned above, I would really like to avoid this approach.

**2. SQL View** - The challenge here is that some of the tables are very large, so if I try to load the view and then filter it on the form, it has to pull the entire recordset from the SQL server, even though I only need a small number of rows. (Negative performance and IO impact.)

**3. Use `context_info`** - This sounds intriguing, but does not sound like a recommended approach based on discussion here: [Create parameterized VIEW in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498364/create-parameterized-view-in-sql-server-2008)  If I was developing against SQL Server 2016 I might look more into [SESSION_CONTEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql).

**4. Parameter Table with View** - This is an idea that I am leaning towards. I would create a `Parameters` table in SQL, and set the parameter value (as a key/value pair) with the session ID. The view would then filter based on the current value in the parameter table. This would allow me to use a view as my `RecordSource` to support the edits, but the filtering would take place on the SQL Server side.

Is the parameter table indeed the **best approach** to take with this project, or is there another way that I could access a parameterized read-write recordset that is filtered on the server side?

Comment: This question seems broad and opinion-based to me. Why can't you use a simple pass-through query with parameters? If maintainability is of importance, that makes it even more dependent on your expertise and exact setup.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - This is an ADP Project, which doesn't support pass-through queries. You are working directly with Views and Stored Proceedures on the SQL side.

Comment: I don't mean a pass-through query as in the DAO pass-through query sense. Just an ADODB recordset set to a parameterized query.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - I am not sure I am quite understanding what you mean by a "parameterized query"... If I use an SP as the recordset on the form, the data is not editable. If I use a View, I cannot set parameters.

Comment: Just use static SQL with parameters. You can save the SQL in a string in the module, or pretty much anywhere else. Alternatively, you can use a TVF to create an updateable recordset if you prefer to manage the query in SQL server.

Comment: Why not use linked table(s) which are editable? And have forms bounded to filtered version of table(s). No in-memory recordsets needed.

Comment: @Parfait - The recordsets often include joins to many different tables. That's one reason coding static SQL in VBA was a concern, because the complex queries are hard to read, and easily broken by database changes.

Comment: Hard to answer without an issue presented here. However the time you are spending to find a cure should be invested to convert the ADP to accdb as your app is living in an unsupported/depreciated time. The sooner you convert the quicker you finish :)

Comment: @krishKM - I hear you! The problem is I inherited this project with over 20,000 lines of VBA code, 500+ SQL views, 281 forms, 177 reports, etc... in a live mission-critical production system. Every programmer's dream, right?  :-)   Yes, I would love to recreate it properly as an accdb, but as you can imagine, that is a massive project. In the mean time I am working to cut away what is not currently being used so we have less to support going forward.

Comment: Puhh! That can be done in a weekend with some scripting :) as most things will stay the same. Plus you can develop in parallel. You will be using odbc connector and if multi user, you must have a mean to generate connection string dynamically.

Comment: well, if it is a ADP, then in most cases it will only pull the reocrds you request into a form - not really sure this is a problem or issue. However,  you have to start REAL quick in terms of converting this to a accDB. ADP's are only supported up to access 2010. We now on 2016, and the click is ticking on your application. See my post below in which I outline how to deal with this issue with a accDB - but really, much of what I stated applies to the depreciated ADPs also.

Comment: and no - access does NOT pull the whole table if you open a form using the "where" clause - even when it is bound diectlly to the table or a view. This advice applies to ADP and regular accDB applications that use SQL server as the back end. So you running on a bit of a wild goose chase in regards to the false narrative that Access pulls all records into a form - it does not and RARE does as long as you the developer provide a "where" clause to restrict the records loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you talking about a non adp project now.

Even if you don’t use a view, and say bind a form directly to a linked table of 1 million rows, then access will ONLY pull down the records you requests. You simply just use the forms “where” clause of the open Form command.

So you don’t even have to use dynamic sql here.

However, you don’t want to launch a form bound to large table UNLESS you set the where clause.

You can certainly open a form without a reordsource, have the user enter some parameter values into a text box, and then go:

```
Dim strSQL   as string

strSQL = "select * from tblCustomers where InvoiceNum = " &     me.MyInvoiceTextBox

Me.RecordSoruce = strSQL
```

However, in most cases you better to create some type of search form. Let the user enter some values, display the results like this:

[image]

So in above, the person type in "smi". You display the results
(and in above I did use the above approach of stuffing the sql directly into the forms reocrdsource

Now on the edit buttons along the side to launch + edit one record,
I  simply go:

```
Docmd.OpenForm "frmCustomer",,,id = & me!id
```

Once again, EVEN if the form is bound directly to the linked SQL server table, only the ONE record will be pulled from SQL server. So no messing with sql, no messing with parameters etc. is required.

So a regular non ADP access application with linked tables DOES NOT pull the whole table.

You can also after opening a form set the forms filter – and again access will ONLY pull the reocrds in question from the linked sql table. It is a “common” myth that access pulls all records – it does not if you provide a filter, and I recommend you open a form to one record, let the user work then close the form and return back to some search screen in which you ready to do battle with the next customer etc.

so provide a search form - don't recommend having the form to edit data be all cluttered up with the ability to search records. Let the user edit, and then close the form - this also promotes the record being saved after the user done working.

edit:
For a form that has any kind of complex joins etc., then create a view, and bind the form to that view. You use the forms "where" clause, then once again access will only pull down the one record. So for complex joins etc., yes access can often mess that query up and it runs slow. So if the form is bound to one table (that is MOST cases), then bind the form directly to the linked table. If the sql is complex, then bind the form to the linked view, and as noted in either case ALWAYS provide a "where clause" to the openform command - it will in these cases ONLY pull the one record into the form. And once again, no messy parameters, no messy sql is required on the access side - you will save MASSIVE amounts of coding if  you adopt this approach, and you also get stellar performance since you limiting the reocrds pulled into that form from sql server.

Comment: Thanks, Albert! Not sure how I overlooked that option, but the `Where` clause in `DoCmd.OpenForm` should meet the need in the majority of cases. Thank you so much for your time in detailing this answer.