# How to a add a condition in the where clause in SQL query based on a variable value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetBenefitCategory(
@BenefitCategoryID INT = 0
)
AS

IF @BenefitCategoryID = 0
SELECT * FROM BenefitCategory
ELSE
SELECT * FROM BenefitCategory Where BenefitCategoryID = @BenefitCategoryID
```

I need to write a SP where i need to add a condition is Where clause as above if the benefitcategoryID is supplied as a input parameter to the SP.

Is there a better of achieving this rather than using a IF ELSE condition.

Actually, my query is very big and i need to add only one condition in the where clause based on the input parameter for the procedure, hence didn't wanted to write redundant code in the SP with IF ELSE condition.

Please let me know if there is a better way of achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

You can express the logic as:

```
SELECT *
FROM BenefitCategory 
WHERE BenefitCategoryID = @BenefitCategoryID OR @BenefitCategoryID = 0;
```

However, this may not have optimal performance, because the `OR` is likely to prevent the use of an index.  One method around this is `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM BenefitCategory 
WHERE BenefitCategoryID = @BenefitCategoryID
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM BenefitCategory 
WHERE @BenefitCategoryID = 0;
```

However, this repeat the query, which isn't desirable.

So, you have a few options.  If you don't care about performance (say the table is small so index usage is not important), then the first method is fine.  If you do, you can use the first method and force a re-compile.  One common alternative -- particularly for somewhat complex queries that take some time to run -- is dynamic SQL.  This prevents the `OR`, so the query can be readily optimized.

And, there is your solution.  It is quite reasonable.  The only caveat I would add is that the stored procedure could be a stored function (unless you use dynamic SQL).  That is usually easier to work with in other parts of the code.

Comment: For the second, be carefull if exists an id equal to 0 (I know it's rare but you never know), else modify your union all to union ;)

Comment: @Esperento57 . . . I think that should be directed to the OP.  The use of `0` is in the question, so I assume it is a safe value to use for "all".  More typically, `NULL` is used for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a parameterized View (with a default value for the parameter). A Parameterized View has the advantage of being indexable.

You get all the advantages of

```
SELECT *
FROM BenefitCategory 
WHERE BenefitCategoryID = @BenefitCategoryID OR @BenefitCategoryID = 0;
```

and also it's compiled and (possibly) indexed. Another way would be

```
SELECT *
INTO #tempTable 
FROM BenefitCategory 

IF (@BenefitCategoryID = 0) 
    SELECT * INTO #tempTable1 FROM #tempTable
ELSE Select * INTO #tempTable1  
     WHERE BenefitCategoryID = @BenefitCategoryID

SELECT * from #tempTable1;
```

and repeat the process if you have many more situations, so that your temp tables keep getting smaller and smaller. But that really depends on how small your category table is, and how elaborate your filtering (where clauses) are.

Comment: I have never heard of a parameterized view, I don't think this is possible. Prove me wrong please

Comment: Inline table functions, sorry... you are so subtle...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498364/create-parameterized-view-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

The best way to write the query for this scenario to use IIF statement.

Use this below query if the BenefitCategoryID  is not null column, its most likely in this case.

```
SELECT * FROM BenefitCategory Where BenefitCategoryID = 
iif(@BenefitCategoryID=0,BenefitCategoryID,@BenefitCategoryID)
```

Below link to learn more about the IIF statement
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This will exclude rows where BenefitCategoryID is null. Most likely this is a not null column,  just pointing out the risk using this method

Comment: yes, its most likely its seems like a not-nullable field BenefitCategoryID in this case. this solution would not work for column which is nullable column. update the response as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method is using dynamic sql. This is very simplified, using the example you have, however:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetBenefitCategory (@BenefitCategoryID int = 0)
AS

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(10) +
               N'FROM BenefitCategory' + NCHAR(10) +
               N'WHERE {Your Other Where Clauses}' + 
               IIF(@BenefitCategoryID = 0, N';', + NCHAR(10) + N'  AND BenefitCategoryID = @dBenefitCategoryID;');
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'dBenefitCategoryID int', @dBenefitCategoryID = @BenefitCategoryID;
GO
```

Comment: @LongChalk `BEGIN`/`END` aren't required for an SP.