# SQL Server stored procedure rewrite

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below set of data which is coming from a view. I have written a stored procedure to count the open and closed tickets per category depending on createdate selected, and I now want to convert it to a view that does exactly the same thing but don't know how to.

Data Model:

```
| Category         | Status | CreateDate |
|------------------|--------|------------|
| Other ...        | Closed | 11/25/2019 |
| ERP - JD Edwards | Open   | 11/25/2019 |
| ERP - JD Edwards | Closed | 11/25/2019 |
| Other ...        | Closed | 11/25/2019 |
| Other ...        | Closed | 11/25/2019 |
| Other ...        | Closed | 11/25/2019 |
| ERP - JD Edwards | Closed | 11/25/2019 |
| ERP - JD Edwards | Closed | 11/25/2019 |
| ERP - JD Edwards | Open   | 11/25/2019 |
| ERP - JD Edwards | Open   | 11/25/2019 |
| Weighbridge      | Closed | 11/25/2019 |
| Other ...        | Closed | 11/25/2019 |
| Other ...        | Closed | 11/25/2019 |
| ERP - JD Edwards | Open   | 11/25/2019 |
| ERP - JD Edwards | Open   | 11/25/2019 |
| ERP - JD Edwards | Closed | 11/25/2019 |
| ERP - JD Edwards | Closed | 11/25/2019 |
| ERP - JD Edwards | Closed | 11/25/2019 |
| ERP - JD Edwards | Open   | 11/25/2019 |
| E-Mail - Outlook | Closed | 11/25/2019 |
| Password Related | Open   | 11/25/2019 |
| ERP - JD Edwards | Closed | 11/25/2019 |
```

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ShowTicketsByCategory]  
    @dtFrom as datetime = NULL,
    @dtTo as datetime = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT category, 
    count(*) AS TotalTickets FROM v_HDeskTicketStatus WHERE CreateDate  >= @dtFrom AND CreateDate < @dtTo 
    GROUP BY category 
END
```

Comment: Views are used to "view" the data, not manipulate it.  If you want to incorporate other control logic, you need to stick with an SP / function.  The same thing applies if you want to parameterize your query, like you show in the `SELECT` above.

Comment: @ravioli thanks for clearing that out for me.

Comment: No problem.  This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498364/create-parameterized-view-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: I'm using the stored procedure to populate a report with data in Devexpress but somehow its failing to execute. I wanted an alternative that doesn't require parameters.

Comment: What is the exact error message?  How else would you have a variable `create_date` without using parameters?

Comment: Error when trying to populate the datasource. The following exception was thrown: Query sp_ShowTicketsByCategory failed to execute. seen from  ASP.NET application

Comment: So will the end user still need to specify a date range or will this view be set to a specific 'fixed' date range?